# Disabling Stretchability of Unicode Character 0640 with Fontforge

Tags: unicode, fonts, fontforge

How can I disable the stretchability of unicode character 0640 (Arabic Tatweel or Kashida) with fontforge. I want to make it a simple fixed size character like all other ones because some apps and browsers (e.g. Chrome) fail to render it properly. I searched thoroughly but couldn't find answers here or anywhere else. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks.

I don't need to disable the stretch-ability of u0640 any more. I wanted to do that to resolve the incorrect rendering when several marks are positioned above it. They just failed to position properly. What I did was create a ligature combining the multiple marks. It is not the ideal solution, but a workaround that worked.